# How i can hide some of page numbers in result page?

Tags: php, paginator

Here is the code that i am using to print the number of pages in my result page.

```
<?PHP
echo '<div style="clear:both;display:block;bottom:0;float:right;margin-right:20px;">';
for($i=1; $i<=$page_count; $i++) {
    if($i == $requested_page) {
        echo "<span class='pagenumberSelected'><b>$i</b></span> ";
    } else {
        echo '<a href="index.php?page='.$i.'" class="pagenumber"><b>'.$i.'</b></a> ';
    }
}
echo '</div><br>';
?>
```

Now it's showing like this:

```
[1] [2] [3] [4] [5] [6] [7] [8] [8] [10] [11] [12] [13] [14] [15]
```

I want to ask how i can hide some of the page numbers on the result page so they show like this:

```
[First] [Back] [1] [2] [3] [4] [5] ..... [10] [11] [12] [13] [14] [15] [Next] [Show Last]
```

So what i must change to make it look like this i want to show 5 pages from the current opened and last 5 pages from the all results.

Comment: Find the boundaries of your range and then just test the page numbers against an if condition to decide whether to show based on where you are and the two sets of 5 at the end of each boundary.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply some logic to this:

```
$currPage = 3;
$totalPages = 10;

echo '[First] [Back] ';

for($i=1; $i<=$totalPages; $i++) {
    if ($i > 3 && $i< 8) {
       echo ' . . . ';
    } else {
       echo '[<a href="your_link.php?page='.$i.'">' . $i . '</a>] ';
    }
}

echo '[Next] [Last] ';
```

each page should have a link to which page it links to.

```
$next  = $currPage + 1;
$prev  = $currPage - 1;
$first = 1;
$last  = $totalPages;
```

to avoid out of boundaries error:

```
if ($next > $totalPages) $next = $totalPages;
if ($prev < 1) $prev = 1;
```

**Above prints:**

```
[First] [Back] [1] [2] [3] . . . . . . . . . . . . [8] [9] [10] [Next] [Last]
```

Comment: It's not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way:

```
$page_count = 15;
$limit = 8;

for($i=1; $i<=$page_count; $i++) {
    if ($i <= ($limit / 2) || $i > ($page_count - ($limit / 2))) {
        echo "[$i] ";
    } else {
        echo '. ';
    }
}
```